# Configure npm's package-lock.json to prevent pruning a specific module

Tags: npm, pruning

So, at the risk of inciting knee jerk responses of "why would you ever want to do that?!?!"... Does anyone know of a config setting one could put into either `package.json` or the generated `package-lock.json` such that npm will ignore a given module when updating/pruning?

Basically I'd like to have some code inside the node_modules directory tree which npm ignores.  This used to be trivial before auto-pruning.  I can, of course, use `--no-package-lock` to prevent auto-pruning, but what I would actually like to do is allow normal pruning behavior except for specific module(s).